# How do I prove that then $f(x) = 1$ for some $x ∈ [0, 1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, continuity, rolles-theorem

We are asked the following:

> let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[0, 1]$ such that
>   $$\int _ {0} ^ {1} \ f(y) dy = 1$$
>   prove that $f(x) = 1$ for some $x ∈ [0, 1]$

The question asks to take into account Rolle's Theorem and Mean Value Theorem.  I'm aware of the definitions, but I am really unsure how to answer this question and my tutors are not really responding till after easter.

Could someone please help? Why is there a "y" involved?

Thanks you

Comment: Thank you for the editions!

Comment: As for the $y$: note that $\int _ {0} ^ {1} \ f(y) dy$,$\int _ {0} ^ {1} \ f(x) dx$, and $\int _ {0} ^ {1} \ f(\textbf{cat}) d\textbf{cat}$ all mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @omnomnomnom .... and who does love $d\,cat$?

Comment: @Dr.MV dog people, I guess

Comment: Yes, unless the dog person is also a cat person.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(x)=\int\limits_0^x f(t)dt$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus this function is continuous and differentiable on $(0,1)$, the derivative at $x$ is $f(x)$.

Now apply the mean value theorem to conclude there is a point $z$ in $(0,1)$ with $F'(z)=1$, of course $F'(z)=f(z)$ so we are done.

Comment: Thank you! However, I am still a little unsure on where y comes into this.  How I can integrate y into the question.  Is it unimportant?

Comment: in this context $y$ can be switched for any other variable and the meaning would not change.

Comment: How would you also apply Rolle's theorem, or is it not necessary?

Comment: the mean value theorem is stronger than rolle

Answer (score 0):

Assume  there is not x  such that $f(x)=1$. Then $f(x)>1$ or $f(x)<1$ for all x . So the integral is either less or greater than 1, contradiction.

Comment: How would you prove that if $f$ is always larger than $1$ then $\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx> 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to Jorge, I think I've figured it out.  My full answer would be:

We know $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Set $F(x)$ = $\int\limits_0^x f(y)dy$

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus shows that the function is differentiable on $(0,1)$.  Also it implies $F'(x) = f(x)$.

Using The Mean-Value Theorem:

$F'(x)$ = $\frac{F(1)-F(0)}{1-0}$

Since $F(1)$ = $\int\limits_0^1 f(y)dy$ = $1$
and $F(0) = 0$

$F'(x) = f(x) = 1$ for some $x$ in $[0,1]$

I think this would be the way to answer it.

Comment: yup, I think thats very good.